# how to convert string to unsigned short using boost lexical cast?

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

I have a string containing the port, when I try to create a tcp endpoint I need its value in unsigned short

```
  std::string to_port;
    ....
    boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(to_port));
```

throws an exception                                                                            `bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target`

Comment: It works for me. What does `to_port` contain?

Comment: e.g. "8004" or any port number

Comment: Does [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5318113dc6ceca259cc3ec1af87cd54c-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc) not work for you?

Comment: please send us the full (but minimal) program that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Might want to stick a break point on the line with the `lexical_cast<>` and verify the content of `to_port` is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following program works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::string to_port("8004");
    unsigned short intport = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(to_port);

    std::cout << intport << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << intport << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But if we modify the first line of `main` into:

```
std::string to_port;
```

We get the exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Which leads to the conclusion that there's something wrong with the parameter you are passing to the `lexical_cast`.

Can you print the `to_port` variable to verify its content just before the `lexical_cast`?
Are you sure it is properly initialized and still in-scope when used (e.g., no temporaries involved, no dangling pointers)?